# How to order result in ascending order if it is Month Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to sum values from two different tables and find sale and purchase per month. After that I am ordering it in ascending order and as expected its giving false result, i.e August is coming before February.

How can I modify my query to get result correctly?

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT COALESCE(o.Month , p.Month) Month,
        ISNULL([Sale Cost],0) [Sale Cost],
        ISNULL([Purchase Cost],0) [Purchase Cost]
 FROM (
     Select sum(S.Cost) AS [Purchase Cost],
            DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(S.[Date_Added]) , -1 ) ) As Month
     from dbo.Spare_Inventory AS S
     where YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(S.[Date_Added])
     GROUP BY month(S.[Date_Added])
     ) o
 FULL JOIN (
     Select sum(B.[Total Price]) AS [Sale Cost],
            DateName(month, DateAdd( month , month(B.[DateOfSale]) , -1 ) ) As Month
     from dbo.Spare_Sale_DB AS B
     where YEAR(GETDATE()) = YEAR(B.[DateOfSale])
     GROUP BY month(B.[DateOfSale])) p
 ON o.Month = p.Month
 ORDER BY Month Asc
```

Comment: Which database  you are using?

Comment: You can also add Month(month) as MonthNum in your select and order by it. The way you are doing it, you are sorting alphabetically on month name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have kind of given the answer yourself; you want your rows oredered by month number, not by month name. So just order by month number.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(o.Month , p.Month) Month,
  ISNULL([Sale Cost],0) [Sale Cost] , 
  ISNULL([Purchase Cost],0)[Purchase Cost]
 FROM 
(
  Select 
    sum(S.Cost) AS [Purchase Cost], 
    DateAdd( month , month(S.[Date_Added]) , -1 ) As MonthNo,
    DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(S.[Date_Added]) , -1 ) ) As Month 
  from dbo.Spare_Inventory AS S 
  where YEAR(GETDATE())=YEAR(S.[Date_Added]) 
  GROUP BY month(S.[Date_Added]) 
) o
FULL JOIN 
(
  Select 
    sum(B.[Total Price]) AS [Sale Cost], 
    DateName( month , DateAdd( month , month(B.[DateOfSale]) , -1 ) ) As Month 
  from dbo.Spare_Sale_DB AS B 
  where YEAR(GETDATE())=YEAR(B.[DateOfSale]) GROUP BY month(B.[DateOfSale])
) p ON o.Month = p.Month
ORDER BY o.MonthNo Asc;
```